# How to generate oracle SQL XML format

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle10g

I would like to generate Oracle SQL in XML format in this result.
My query as following:

```
Select xmlelement(“main”,xmlelement(“id”,id)) from tableA

<main>
  <id>1</id>
  <id>2</id>
</main>
```

But I always get this result

```
<main>
  <id>1</id>
</main>
<main>
  <id>2</id>
</main>
```

Help please thanks

Edit:
I only need 1  per execution query,
Not by row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the results set to be processed per row then you need to aggregate over multiple rows. When you are working with numbers, you can use aggregation functions like `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, etc.; for strings you can use the `LISTAGG` function; but for XML data you will want the `XMLAGG` function:

```sql
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
         "main",
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT("id",id)
         )
       ) AS xml
FROM   tableA
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tableA ( id ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | XML                               |
> | :-------------------------------- |
> | <main><id>1</id><id>2</id></main> |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=72f47adfc6c295347b7d1ef426a7ed57)*